# Where I can ask for recomendation on books on databases?

Tags: discussion, questions, books, database

Normally I would ask on Stack Overflow, but after reading the rules I am positive that it is not the right place.

I am not even sure if this is the right place to ask this "meta" question?

Comment: Nowhere. Recommendation questions (afaik) are off-topic within the entire network.

Comment: The only place would be an appropriate chatroom. Broad recommendation questions (about books or anything else) simply don't work with the Q&A philosophy and format of the site. Nothing inherently wrong with these questions, but Stack Exchange is focused on something else: practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Comment: Book recommendation questions about databases specifically are most likely welcome in [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) - where the over-arching topic is databases but we talk about a broad range of things.

Comment: The question that this question has been flagged to be a duplicate of is not available anymore. Please unflag it or post another question.

Comment: bahaha the referenced issue in the closed tag has been deleted. I thought you were never going to delete stuff stackexchange. Which is why you want relevant parts of links to be copied here, in case the links go stale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no *Stack Exchange* site where you can ask about recommendations. That does not fit a Q&A site. We don't want answers getting outdated or being subjective.

Since today there is a [brand new site for Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).